# filtering a table by ids of another table in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So lets say i have a table mappedIds of an entity from linq, which has a relationship with another table named finishedDownloads on its column categoryID. How do i make a new table of mappedIds that contain no ids found in finishedDownloads?

I understand the commands like where and except, but im just not sure how to say, look at this id, and compare it to that id.

I'm looking for the equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM  mappedIds mIDs WHERE mIDs.CategoryID NOT IN
(SELECT categoryID FROM finishedDownloads)
```

Edit: Mapped Ids is stored in a Table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say how your context is set, but even if it's not exactly as I think it is you can easily see the idea:

```
var results = _context.MappedIds
                      .Where(x => !_context.FinishedDownloads
                                           .Select(f => f.categoryID)
                                           .Contains(x.CategoryID));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var idList = finishedDownloads.Select(f => f.categoryID);

var result = mappedIds.Where(m => !idList.Contains(m.CategoryID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var result = mappedIds.Select(m=>m.CategoryId).Except(finishedDownloads
                                                       .Select(f=>f.categoryId));
```

Comment: I get a cannot implicitly convert iqueriable<int> to table<cccMap> does this just get the ints?

Comment: @Ukemi Yes the result will contains only the ids which are present in `mappedIds` but not in `finishedDownloads`.